# Datetimepicker value resets on incorrect submit and page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want the value of the datetimepicker to persist on page refresh, and not be reset to default. The value (:deadline) is stored in the params hash, and I would like to set the value of the datetimepicker to params[:deadline] on page refresh or if incorrect information is submitted in my form.

Can this be done or should I use session instead?

Here is my attempt at solving this problem:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ 
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
            minDate: moment().add(1, 'd').toDate(),
            if(#{params.has_key?(:deadline)}){ // What I tried
                $("#datetimepicker1").value("2018-06-20");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<%= f.label :deadline %>
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <%= f.text_field :deadline, class: "form-control" %>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a value for your input based on `deadline` attribute and change the `minDate` to `defaultDate`:

```
<%= f.label :deadline %>
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <%= f.text_field :deadline, class: "form-control", value: @my_object.deadline %>
</div>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ 
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
      useCurrent: false,
      minDate: moment().add(1, 'd').toDate()
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't fully work, as former dates will be selectable. I had to include useCurrent: false for it to work.